# how do I test if a text field is left blank after a button press?

Tags: android, testing

I have an Android application where this interface contains 3 text fields. I have to perform unit testing, which is somewhat similar to JUnit testing where it displays a red/green bar in its results. For example, how do I test if any messages or exceptions are thrown should i click on a button with 1 of the text fields left blank?

Any suggestions or examples are welcome. I would like to make this work so much. I have been looking at my attempt below for a long time, & have yet to figure out how I should do this. Am new to Android testing please bear with me.

Snippet:

```
public void submitNew(View v){
        int hour = tp.getCurrentHour();
        int minute = tp.getCurrentMinute();
        String apptTime = Integer.toString(hour) + Integer.toString(minute);
        if (apptTime.length()<4)
            apptTime = "0" + apptTime;


        //Original statement commented out
        //String apptPlace = et.getText().toString();

        //Original statement with invalid input (3rd variable - Place)
        String apptPlace = "";      


        int day = dp.getDayOfMonth();
        int month = dp.getMonth()+1;
        int year =  dp.getYear();
        String apptDate = Integer.toString(day) + "/" +  Integer.toString(month) + "/" + Integer.toString(year);
        String appt = apptDate + "," + apptTime + "," + apptPlace;
        addUpcomingSet(appt);       
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DoctorAppointment.class);
        startActivity(intent);      


        //call returnResult()
        if (appt != null) {     
            result = 1;         //implies that obj != empty                 
        }           
    }

    //method to be called within submitNew()
    public int returnResult() {     
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure if what you mean, but if you simply want to test if an `EditText` is blank on button click you can do the following:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String editTextString = editText.getText().toString();
            if (editTextString.isEmpty() {
                //do what you want to here
            }
        }

    });
```

Again, I'm not entirely sure of what you wish to do, but this will check if the `EditText` field is empty on button press.

Comment: thank you sir. What i wish to do is somewhat similar to JUnit testing, where it displays if a test produced correct results (green/red bar). Sorry to have been unclear

Answer (score 0):

```
    Get the String on button click as follow 
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String check = editText1.getText().toString();
                if (check.equals("") || check.length()==0) {
                    //Use your code on condition true
                }
            }

        });
```